# What exactly is .csv in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, machine-learning-model

I already have dataset of dogs and cats , so do i need to make .csv file or can i directly use the dataset for classification

Comment: Hello Chinmayg, welcome to the site. Your question is not very clear. CSV = Comma Separated Value. It is a file format for storing tabular information. If you make you question more clear, we can better help you. How does your current dataset look like, are the dogs and cats images? Why do you tag SVM? What programming language are you using? What packages are you using?  If you improve your question I will be glad to help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Answer (score 1):

A csv file is a way to store an array (similar to an excel table). 
With a code like this one, you can save a pandas dataframe to a csv file:

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'c2':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})
 df.to_csv('df.csv')
```

which will look like that

```
,c1,c2
0,1,a
1,2,b
2,3,c
3,4,d
```